# Sporadic BSOD Windows 10 evidence pointing to "iaStorA.sys"

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod

This is starting to drive me insane, my machine seems to BSOD every 4-5 hours. Usually while I am actively working in Visual Studio 2015 debugging a Web Form application, but sometimes when I am away from the computer.

It also seems to restart itself whenever I put it to "sleep" overnight instead of resuming, I don't know if this is another silent BSOD.

So far I have:

- Tried microsoft support using the QR code (useless)
- Freed up more space on my SSD boot drive (as it was 99% full)
- Ran CCleaner Reg fix
- Disabled some start up applications related to Alienware and Dell
- Updated the "killer" network drivers
- Used the Intel Driver Update Utility to attempt to update drivers
- Investigated through BLueScreenView and event log which points to iaStoreA.sys (which is what lead me to updating the intel drivers but it stil BSODs)

I am currently on a google hunt on how to update the specific driver ["iastorea.sys"](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=update%20iaStorA.sys) which is bringing up lots of BSOD posts

But I was really hoping someone had come across this before and could get me on the right track, its got me going round the bend. Here is the information I am using screen grabbed. Let me know if there is anywhere else I can dig!

[image: BSOD details]

[image: Device information]

Comment: Are you using a RAID? The driver is part of the Intel Matrix Storage driver, so unless you're using a RAID, this shouldn't be necessary, but worth updating it regardless. You can install the updated driver from here - https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26361/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-RAID-Driver?product=55005 - It's worth noting that the driver name might be differen't as on newer builds, the SYS file is named iastore.sys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment, the files is part of the intel SATA RAID Driver. The file is required for usage with SATA and RAID drives.

There are known incompatibilities between some Intel Matrix Storage drivers and W10, so the best approach to a fix is to update your chipset drivers and Intel Matrix Storage drivers to their latest version. Finally, update W10.

Before installing the latest version, you should try to remove the current one, by going into Device Manager to find the listing for SCSI/SATA/RAID Controllers and click on that and select 'Uninstall Driver" to safely remove it.

Be aware that if you disable RAID mode from BIOS you will not be able to access RAID arrays. Some BIOSes have RAID and SATA as separate options, but in few cases SATA/RAID is all-in-one option, so be careful in this particular case (disabling it disables RAID and puts SATA drives in IDE-compatibility mode).

Comment: I uninstalled the driver, then it told me it wouldn't do anything until I restarted... And I did now windows won't boot :(. Kinda makes sense, it can't find a bookable device.. HELP

Comment: I've managed to reboot the machine by turning off RAID & secure boot in the BIOS and booting into safe mode, then booting the machine... not really sure how to recover RAID

Comment: Remove the intel drivers, install them back, then put back RAID mode in BIOS. You cannot access a RAID array if RAID mode is disabled.

Comment: I might leave RAID off, as I only have one drive and things seems to be more stable in this configuration anyway. thanks

Comment: if you can update the answer to include a warning not to do what i did, I can mark as best answer

Comment: I have updated the answer considering the 2 possibilities of RAID/SATA modes in BIOS.

Comment: that is a good addition but the step of uninstalling the driver is what locked me out on windows 10, because straight after it forced me to restart. Perhaps i did it in the wrong way?

Comment: Unintalling the intel driver is no reason for Windows to become unusable. It has its own basic driver for that. If it is not compatible, the Driver/Array will not show, but if it worked during windows installation without the new intel driver, it will work when uninstalling it too.

Comment: I think the issue I had was I uninstalled the Intel Raid Driver, while in Raid configuration, rebooted, and then there was no default windows Raid driver...I think. In order to get it to stop rebooting I had to go into the BIOS and turn off Secure boot, then turn off raid configuration, then boot in safe mode

Answer (score -1):

Having spent best part of a day on this annoying BSOD with none of the recommendations working for me I finally by chance decided to download and install the Intel drivers fo Rapid Storage Technology 14.*** (sorry cannot recall the actual details other than "14") from the Intel site as none of the "latest" versions appeared to be compatible with my Dell XPS Window 10 Pro set up. Thankfully these worked and the system is stable. I have also disabled any future update for these driver in the Iobit Driver Booster. Given that this functionality is possibly not required in Win 10. begs the question why it cannot just be "removed" once and for all. Tried but appears to be not possible. Hope this assists anyone having the same issues.

Comment: It can certainly be removed, falling back to the generic Microsoft AHCI driver. Have you tried?

Comment: Reluctant to dabble with this anymore; it's fixed for now. Not sure the actual RST makes the slightest bit of difference anyway to the performance of my PC and I certainly do not have RAID. At least no more BSOD for now.